# How to get keyup/keydown/keypress events on a Windows.Forms.Form that is minimized or not focused?

Tags: winforms, events, focus, keyevent

I'd like to know if is possible to get keyup/keydown/keypress events on a Windows.Forms.Form that is minimized or not focused, so, for example, if I press the Ctrl key the event would be executed on the Form.

It's possible to do that? How should I proceed to get this result?

Comment: It is possible, but **not** using the standard Form events.  To trap keypresses when your form is not focused requires the use of a low level keyboard hook.  Do a search for `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and you'll get tons of hits.