# Detecting KeyDown and KeyUp events with no form in focus (nor in foreground)

Tags: c#, forms, events, onkeydown, user32

I wish the user to be able to press the Ctrl, and my form does something and upon releasing this key, the form does something else. Unfortunately, my form may not be in focus (nor the foreground window). How can I achieve this? I'm guessing it's a PInvoke, but a search didn't turn up anything obvious.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: PInvoke is for calling functions from unmanaged dll's, nothing to do with keyboardhooks

Comment: It maynot be possible directly from forms. But possible with windows hooks. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056235/how-to-get-keyup-keydown-keypress-events-on-a-windows-forms-form-that-is-minimiz)

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I'm aware of that :) I meant in the sense that I'm going to have to go the route of invoking some native dll methods (user32.dll no doubt) to get the functionality I'm after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SetWindowsHook for this. You application will get a callback when the keyboard is triggered.

You should checkout this example code:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx